# include null and zero in count() from related table

Tags: mysql

I would like to list in table (*staging*) the number of related records from table (*studies*).

So far this statement works well but returns only the rows where there are >0 related records:

```
SELECT staging.*, 
COUNT(studies.PMID) AS refcount 
FROM studies
LEFT JOIN staging
ON studies.rs_number = staging.rs
GROUP BY staging.idstaging;
```

How can I adjust this statement to list ALL rows in table (*staging*) including where there are zero or null related records from table (*studies*)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the tables in the wrong order in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT staging.*, COUNT(studies.PMID) AS refcount 
FROM staging LEFT JOIN
     studies
     ON studies.rs_number = staging.rs
GROUP BY staging.idstaging;
```

`LEFT JOIN` keeps everything in the first ("left") table and all matching rows in the second.  If you want to keep everything in the `staging` table, then put it first.

And, in case anyone wants to complain about the use of `staging.*` with `GROUP BY`.  This particular usage is (presumably) ANSI compliant because `staging.idstaging` is (presumably) a unique id in that table.